# Get-AzureADGroup ReportToManagerEnabled check

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, distribution-list

I have a DL that is currently not getting bounce backs/NDR's. This DL is unfortunately not on prem so I have to use AzureAD in powershell.

Normally in the Exchange shell you can run `Get-DistributionGroup distributiongroup@yourserver.com | FL *report*`

This will show you `ReportToManagerEnabled` being set to either True or False

I can run `get-azureadgroup objectIDxxxxxx` but do not know how to get or set `ReportToManagerEnabled`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  This set the flag for me, but I am still having NDR problems.

Set-DistributionGroup   "DistributionGroupName"   -ReportToManagerEnabled  $true